# Why can't connect to biometric through direct Ethernet connection?

Tags: networking

I have this biometric device (brand and model is ZKTECO K30) that I can't ping or connect to.

I'm using a cross-over Ethernet cable to connect it and also the device IP is `192.168.2.63` then the computer IP is `192.168.2.1`.

My problem is I can't connect to this device even though they are physically connected.

PS: No router involved it's physically connected.

Comment: Do both your biometric device and your computer's network card have a manually assigned subnet mask of `255.255.255.0`?

Comment: Yes it has, it's 255.255.255.0

Comment: Does your computer have another Ethernet interface that's using 192.168 (with a different mask or also .2)? Were you able to ping it before? Check out [how to ask a good question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: After trying to ping it, does the device show up in your ARP cache (`arp` command)? Have you tried using a non-crossover cable?

Comment: I also have tried straight through cable. but i still can't ping the device and can't see in arp -a command and also can't ping it before, no one using the 192.168 other than the device I configured and static IP that i input to my PC.

Answer (score 1):

The default port number is `4370`.

From your PC, try entering this in your web browser:

```
192.168.2.63:4370
```

Comment: it's not working.

Comment: Try opening a ticket with ZKTeco support: https://www.zkteco.com/en/service.html They can probably fix this very quickly.